# How can I get a researcher to research a drug for my affliction?

Tags: medications

I have a relatively rare disease, and just recently discovered that a drug helps me with some of my symptoms. The drug is not approved by the FDA for how I am using it.

Who do I contact, and how do I contact them, to get the research done so that this drug can become approved by the FDA for how I am using it?

Comment: What disease?  do you already have an idea about how to develop a treatment?

Answer (score 2):

You can contact the FDA from their website, [fda.gov](http://www.fda.gov/).

Since you're a patient with a disease, I would use the FDA Patient Network Program.

Office of Health and Constituent Affairs: 301-796-8460; email: PatientNetwork@fda.hhs.gov

Please note that your doctor does not need FDA approval to use a drug in an off-label manner.

> Can there be any problems for doctor if a drug is prescribed for conditions that are not on the label or FDA-approved?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can explain a little more on off-label use of drugs. Can there be any problems for doctor if a drug is prescribed for conditions that are not on the label or FDA-approved?

Comment: @mso - Can you please ask that in a separate question? It's a good question and deserves more than an aside.

Comment: I don't want to explain much more than I have as I must now obtain the drug without a prescription. I do not like having to bend the law in order to get by with the symptoms of my disease. I would prefer to obtain the drug through a pharmacy even if it more expensive that way. My doctor tells me that he is prohibited from prescribing the drug that I am using.

Comment: @anongoodnurse : Please see this new question: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3144/off-label-prescribing-of-drugs

Comment: NBR has a relevant story on the prices of drugs  http://nbr.com/2015/09/16/sick-of-sky-high-drug-prices-heres-a-revenge-prescription/