# Can a drug to be used in the clinic to treat a disease that failed a clinical trial?

Tags: medications, cancer

I am searching for drugs for my uncle who has prostate cancer who is afraid to take corticosteroids. I read about the drug cabozantinib, but it said it failed a 3rd phase clinical trial, even though it was equally as effective as the treatment with corticosteroids, only more expensive. Since it has not been approved due to this, I am wondering if this drug can still be used for prostate cancer?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you are asking. Do you mean to ask whether generally drugs can be prescribed by physicians for something other than what they are intended to treat? If so, does  https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3144/off-label-prescribing-of-drugs answer your question?

Comment: So your uncle is afraid to try corticosteroids for a very serious ailment and prefers a drug of a class so new we have zero data on their long term effects, with the specific drug itself having been used in clinical trials only? Sure, kinase inhibitors are a big topic right now because they have fewer (immediate) side effects than chemo - but steroids also have fewer side effects than chemo.